# i have a SPICE COOLPAD MI 515 AND I CANT ACCESS TO MY STORAGE

Tags: applications, storage

i had not rooted my phone yet but i tried storage swaping intern to ex. but after editing vold.fstab sdcard0 to sdcard1 and restarted my phone. I loss access to my storage after the said restart So how can i get back my storage external as well as phone storage because both does not shown give me suggestion for unrooted phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing the file over an ADB interface.
You can install the appropriate drivers and the ADB Interface, and then use a program called PuTTYTray: https://puttytray.goeswhere.com . There, you can use the built-in Linux text editor using the command called *vi* to edit the vold.fstab file to return your device to its original configuration.